# Salesforce Informatica Acknowledge

Tags: integration, workflowoutboundmessage, informatica

I am trying to use Informatica Cloud's integration with Salesforce with the help of outbound messages.

How do I get the acknowledgement of the success or the error from Informatica and use it for the field update in Saleforce?

Comment: what version/edition of informatica do you have? Free dataloader, Pro, Basic, Enterprise?

Comment: I am using the informatica cloud trial org.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this in multiple of ways.    One way is to use the synch flag on the target side,   that you can bring back into SFDC that marks the record which has successfully synched to the target system.

Comment: But how will i track that the source informatica oubound failed or the source failed. Suppose the in the target field was updated and the source informatica task failed. How will i handle this situation.